# $x_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}-2\sqrt n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

$x_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}-2\sqrt n$

From here [Investigating the convergence of a series using the comparison limit test, Part II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789928/investigating-the-convergence-of-a-series-using-the-comparison-limit-test-part) I can see that the sequence converges. I was trying to use the monotone convergence theorem instead since $x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{-1}{\sqrt {n+1}(\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1})^2}\leq0$. How should I go about guessing the lower bound and using induction and MCT to show convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2(\sqrt n - \sqrt{n-1})=\frac2{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n-1}}\geq\frac1{\sqrt n}\geq\frac2{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}}=2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)$$
So we have $$2\sqrt n\geq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}\geq2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)$$
You only need the lower bound, but it's nice to have an upper bound as well.

Comment: Thanks, this gives $x_n\geq-2$. Can we also find the limit?

Comment: The limit is $\zeta(\frac12)$ where $\zeta$ is the riemann zeta function but that would probably require some more advanced tools.

Answer (score 1):

Since $1/\sqrt{x}$ is a decreasing function,
$$
1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\ge\int_{1}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=2\sqrt{n+1}-2.
$$

Comment: What theorem is being used to arrive at this inequality?

Comment: No need for a theorem. Just draw the graph of $1/\sqrt x$ and a lower Riemann sum.

Comment: So the LHS is an upper riemann sum of $f(x)=1/\sqrt x$ with partition $\{1,2,3,...,n+1\}$ and since the definite integral is defined as the inf of the set of all upper sums, the inequality follows.

Comment: That's right. The method can be used to get also an upper bound.